# Content databases not automatically upgraded by Mount-SPContentdatabase

Tags: upgrade, content-database

We have been told that a good process for accelerating the process of upgrading a farm (say installing a Service Pack) is:

- Detach all content databases.
- Install the Service Pack or Cumulative update.
- Run PSconfig or Wizard.
- Mount again the content databases with *Mount-SPContentDatabase*.

According to the *Mount-SPContentDatabase* documentation, this cmdlet upgrades automatically the content database if it detects that there is a mismatch with the version of the farm.
We have followed the process for upgrading a farm from **SP2010 RTM** to **SP2010 SP2+CU Aug 2013**, but after running *Mount-SPContentDatabase*, all databases appear in status "**Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended**"

Only after running an *Upgrade-SPContentDatabase* they appear as "**No action required**"

Did we miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please give me syntax for the mount command?did you use nob2bupgrade parameter in it?

Comment: I ran a Mount-SPContentDatabase <db> -WebApplication <webapp> -MaxSiteCount <max> -WarningSiteCount <wrn> , I did not use nob2bupgrade.

Comment: it should,what i would do, i will check the Upgrade log and see why it fails to upgrade the content during mount process.

Comment: No errors found in the logs. Even comparing `$db.SchemaVersionXml` of a "**no action required**" and another with "**...compatibility range**", they show up identical results.